# What does "clock sequence" mean?

Tags: uuid, guid, rfc, dce

RFC 4122 (*A Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID) URN Namespace*) uses the term "[clock sequence](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1.5)":

> **4.1.5.  Clock Sequence**

> For UUID version 1, the clock sequence is used to help avoid
> duplicates that could arise when the clock is set backwards in time
> or if the node ID changes.

> If the clock is set backwards, or might have been set backwards
> (e.g., while the system was powered off), and the UUID generator can
> not be sure that no UUIDs were generated with timestamps larger than
> the value to which the clock was set, then the clock sequence has to
> be changed.  If the previous value of the clock sequence is known, it
> can just be incremented; otherwise it should be set to a random or
> high-quality pseudo-random value.

> Similarly, if the node ID changes (e.g., because a network card has
> been moved between machines), setting the clock sequence to a random
> number minimizes the probability of a duplicate due to slight
> differences in the clock settings of the machines.  If the value of
> clock sequence associated with the changed node ID were known, then
> the clock sequence could just be incremented, but that is unlikely.

> The clock sequence MUST be originally (i.e., once in the lifetime of
> a system) initialized to a random number to minimize the correlation
> across systems.  This provides maximum protection against node
> identifiers that may move or switch from system to system rapidly.
> The initial value MUST NOT be correlated to the node identifier.

> For UUID version 3 or 5, the clock sequence is a 14-bit value
> constructed from a name as described in Section 4.3.

> For UUID version 4, clock sequence is a randomly or pseudo-randomly
> generated 14-bit value as described in Section 4.4.

What does this term mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Clock Sequence" seems like a really misleading name.  Based on its definition, a better name might be "Random Component of uuid".

One of uuid's big claims to fame is that if we both generate a UUID value we can be pretty confident that we won't generate the same 128 bit values.  This says something about the likely hood of a collision.

If we had a common coordinator or a pre-agreed scheme we could also be confident that we wouldn't experience a collision.

Potential Schemes:

```
1. Partition Int Space: I get numbers 1-999, you get 1000-1999.
2. Request Reservation: Request 10 numbers and increment a centrally stored max reserved numbers.  You get numbers 1-10.  The next reservation gets 11-20.
```

The big UUID observation is that if you have quite a few bits (16 in this case), it's pretty unlikely for the next requester to get the same random value.

Lotteries are based on this concept.

Comment: I agree that the most appropriate name would be "random component".

Answer (score 3):

The term "clock sequence" is a *misnomer*. It's just a random number, not a sequence.

The clock sequence exists for one purpose only: *to help to avoid duplicates*.

The RFC-4122 says that the clock sequence must be changed when:

- the clock is backwards;
- the clock might have been set backwards;
- the generator is not sure if the clock is backwards or not;
- the node identifier has changed;
- node identifiers are getting mixed up.

The clock sequence "can just be incremented" (like a sequence). But it is a MAY, not a SHOULD. I've found some implementations that always randomize the clock sequence [here](https://github.com/BeyondTrust/pbis-open/blob/7119ef7df165edcdeee345232e60ca7aca68b5ff/dcerpc/uuid/uuid.c#L1606) and [here](https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator/blob/f7ecf34ded9f0cadd7748d9d0761d00060979db8/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/uuid/UUIDTimer.java#L270).

I think the word "sequence" causes confusion. Although the clock sequence behaves like a sequence when it is incremented, it is in fact a random number.

UUID v1 has 3 parts, namely:

- **time** (number of 100-nanos since 15 October 1582);
- **place** (IEEE address);
- **some entropy** (clock sequence).

In this Github issue you can find a discussion about clock sequence: https://github.com/uuid6/uuid6-ietf-draft/issues/41

Answer (score 0):

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9629399/apdxa.htm#tagcjh_20_02_01 talks about the algorithm of how a clock sequence is generated.

In summary, it is a random number generated at the start of the program. It gets increased every time

- It detects the local UTC time goes backward
- The previous UTC time is not set due to application restart

Answer (score -1):

It is one of the fields that makes up the UUID, as defined in section 4.1.2.