# How can I get the clock sequence in .NET 6.0?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to create my own custom UUID and would like to use the clock sequence in it because I know nothing else on my system that auto increments even when the system time is set back.

But how do I get the clock sequence in .NET 6.0?

Edit: Not looking for answers to the question how to create a GUID or why I would want to do that. The question is: How do I get the clock sequence in .NET 6.0?

Comment: This begs the question: why on earth do you want to create your own UUID? That is not a trivial algorithm.

Comment: https://davecallan.com/generating-sequential-guids-which-sort-sql-server-in-net/

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [user3112728](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3112728) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476072/361177) response:

> "Clock Sequence" seems like a really misleading name. Based on its definition, a better name might be "Random Component of uuid".

There is the clock sequence of a given GUID, it's [the forth block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format), you can retrieve it more or less gracefully:

```
Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Split('-')[3]);
```

But there is no such a thing as ***the** clock sequence* (as an [eidos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidos)).
The 4th block of a GUID is generated by **an** algorithm that should follow some rules, but these are not restrictive enough for the implementation to be unique, based on [this post](https://github.com/uuid6/uuid6-ietf-draft/issues/41#issuecomment-907517063) those are:

> The RFC-4122 says that the clock sequence must be changed when:
>
> ```
> the clock is backwards;
> the clock might have been set backwards;
> the generator is not sure if the clock is backwards or not;
> the node identifier changed;
> node identifiers are getting mixed up.
> ```

So basically, if you want to implement **a** clock sequence algorithm, you have to store a value and change it whenever one of these conditions occur.
The *just change it* part is loose, that why there is no unique implementation.

You can go with something like this:

```
// Change clock sequence because clock is backwards
// This is a definitely incomplete example
if (now <= lastTime) {
  clockSequence++
}
```

However, I don't see the point of reinventing [the wheel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid) here.
**Update:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899426), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752004) and [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SequentialGuid) some info/implementations of *sequential* GUIDs;

Comment: Thx. But this won't work between restarts. I'm trying to create my own sequential guid. Guid.NewGuid is not sequential.

Comment: I'm not looking for a different solution. I can think of one myself. I'm looking for an answer to this question though. I would like to know if it is possible in .NET core to get the current clock sequence. Why I need is irrelevant to the question since other people might be looking for the same answer for different reasons.

Comment: ok. I just figured that the current clock sequence could have been some CPU firmware functionality. Gues i figured wrong then.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899426) can help you. I updated my answer to include my previous comments. Again, why you need this may be help-full for future answers.